# How do I modify a pandas dataframe I created in one method of a class in another method of the same class?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-analysis

I created a python class called 'loan' which has a method that produces a pandas data frame of principal and interest payment along with current balance. I now want to create another method which produces the same data frame with additional columns in the same class without copying and pasting the same code from the other method. How can I do that?

Comment: Would you share the code of your class here?

Comment: Try to read this. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can call your first function, let's call it func_A, from your second function, let call it func_B.  Just make sure to save the returned value in a variable in func_B.

Then you just need to add a column to the dataframe, as explained in this article:
https://towardsdatascience.com/4-methods-for-adding-columns-to-pandas-dataframes-dd0696863c16

Comment: Try to answer complete questions. Regards. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer